# How to repeat signal harnesses in Altium?

Tags: schematics, altium

I am relatively new to hierarchical design in Altium but am finding it really powerful as most of my project involve multiple repeated circuits e.g. I design a lot of automotive controllers and PLCs etc.

I am using the repeat command for the first time as I have 24 repeated circuits so 24 sheet symbols is cumbersome. I can repeat ports as show in the first image on the right.

My issue is the repeated harnesses, in my case I have 4 nets attached to a harness, I have repeated this sheet 24 times, I now need to access all of these nets 4x24=96 in total to connect them to a MCU.

I am beginning to think there is no way to do this properly with harnesses so I will have to create individual ports. Is there a way to use the repeat command on sheet symbols while using harnesses?

Or what is a good and neat way of getting a large number of ports from a repeated sheet symbol?

I have tried it various ways but cannot work out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Main Top level sheet]

[image: Sheet that is repeated]

[image: MCU that needs access to all nets]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stick with buses instead of harnesses for this.

For each BTN7030 schematic, have each signal net going to a normal port.

[image]

Name the port with the repeat command, and add a NetLabel for the Net, plus the bus.
Have this bus connect to your MCU sheet with bussed ports

[image]

Use bus entries to access individual nets from each bus as required.

[image]

Comment: This does seem like the best solution, thanks for the answer!