# How to connect Harness to Bus on Altium?

Tags: usb, schematics, altium, bus, usb-pd

I am trying to connect PD Controller to 2 child USB Type C Connector by repeating.

I created Harness connector both PD controller and USB COnnector side. But nets did not connect on the PCB.

How to connect Harness Bus to repeating Harness? Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Main Schematic**
[image: Main Schematic]

**PD Controller Schematic**
[image: PD Controller Schematic]

**USB Connector Schematic**
[image: USB Connector Schematic]

Comment: I've never managed Repeat + Bus + Harness, but it might be possible.
Take a look at this answer which works with Repeats and Buses, without harnesses.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610586/how-to-repeat-signal-harnesses-in-altium/610759

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I guess Altium is not supporting Harness Repeat right now. So to solve this issue, I made another child schematic to get a USB bus and convert it to a harness.